# Web browser: Hide mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, browser

**Is it possible to hide the mouse cursor in a web browser?**

I've done this in Flash for a touch screen application, where a mouse cursor is distracting and unneeded. This time it's for a display screen that is non-interactive, so a mouse cursor is not needed.

My gut feeling is there's no easy way to achieve this in the web browser, only by use of a browser plug-in.

**The browser in use is Firefox**, so perhaps there's a plug-in that achieves this? Although it would be preferable to be able to do this via JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just use a CSS rule:

```
* {
cursor: none;
}
```

Comment: correct - but some browsers will still show the cursor if the document height is not filled / >100% ..

Comment: I'd heard talk about this, but was told it didn't work... it's a nice surprise it does :)

Comment: Works in chrome for me (version 6.0.472.63 on Mac OSX).

Comment: Chrome in Kiosk (full screen with no borders) mode (version 12.0.742.122, windows xp sp3) and with window maximized seem to ignore BODY {cursor: none} and * {cursor: none} -- maybe I misunderstood the answer though.

Comment: Can't edit my last comment (too old?). Chrome in Kiosk mode with * {cursor: none} in css *will* remove the cursor. (version 16.0.912.77 m, on xp sp3)

Answer (score 13):

Finding something that works across browsers is a pain.

The code below works on Chrome, IE, and Firefox. 
IE likes .cur files, Chrome likes the embedded png, and some browsers actually respect the none :)

```
#div {
    cursor: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjbQg61aAAAADUlEQVQYV2P4//8/IwAI/QL/+TZZdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='),
    url(images/blank.cur),
    none !important;
}
```

Comment: To get a set of public domain blank cursors (including .cur): http://pc.autons.net/stuff/blanks/

Comment: Worked for me. Couldn't retrieve the .cur file anywhere so here's another link; [Download blank.cur](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14CctT9tg3cTYx5QDaramFTeVsFW-krKX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can find blank cursors here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120320085351/http://pc.autons.net/stuff/blanks/blank.zip

Answer (score 2):

Try using the CSS:

```
  #elementID{
     cursor: none;
  }
```