# Move mouse cursor using javascript in Chrome or Firefox using any method (Plugin, GreaseMonkey?)

Tags: javascript, dom, plugins, mouse

I have need to move the mouse cursor position in the browser, I can use any method as long as its in Google Chrome or Firefox, one or the other.
In the best case, I would like to control the mouse position with javascript.

Any easy way to do this? Thanks! Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Altough Greasemonkey gives some additional features (like Cross-Server XMLHttpRequests), I don't think this has been implemented.

Perhaps what you are looking for is a feature available for Firefox extensions. But I'm not sure.

Maybe you can emulate this behaviour as in [LMGTFY](http://bit.ly/9BeNGV). You can hide the mouse with CSS, I think.

Edit: I'm using both bit.ly and LMGTFY to stand my point. The question is about hiding a mouse. **Please read before voting and editing, people!**

Comment: Good suggestion faking it :) Hiding the mouse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361404/web-browser-hide-mouse-cursor

Answer (score 2):

From privileged Firefox (JS) code you can call [`nsIDOMWindowUtils.sendNativeMouseEvent(x, y, 0, 0, null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils#sendNativeMouseEvent()) to reposition the mouse cursor, where `(x,y)` is an absolute screen coordinate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39324799/1288130

Answer (score -2):

try this :you can create your own COM object that will registered on client

http://febru.soluvas.com/2015/02/javascript-move-mouse.html