# In XUL or JavaScript, is there a way to move the mouse cursor to specified position?

Tags: javascript, mouse, desktop, xul, xulrunner

In XUL or JavaScript, is there a way to move the mouse cursor to specified position?

Comment: I'd hate to think of the chaos this would cause, if ad networks could control the mouse and force a click on ads.

Comment: @Marc B: it's for a desktop app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Xul, within a transparent window, how do I hide the mouse cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960411/in-xul-within-a-transparent-window-how-do-i-hide-the-mouse-cursor)

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question?  Just go back and update the original one.

Comment: @Pointy I made a question that actually needed to be slip into 2 questions. The question about hiding the mouse was answered correctly, so I wanted to mark the guy's answer as correct. Now I have other 2 questions: this about move the cursor, and the other about hiding cursor in a Xul transparent window..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time that Gecko moves the mouse is on Windows for the snap-to-default-button effect. This is used by XUL [dialogs](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/dialog.xml#192) and wizards. The backend code doesn't actually check that you're giving it a button; any XUL [control](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/general.xml#9) works. The mouse is moved to the centre of the element, if that point is on-screen, and the window is active. Normally the code checks that the system cursor snapping is enabled, but there is a preference that overrides that.

Comment: so, just for windows? no way for moving the cursor on linux?

Comment: @Tom Brito Sorry, you'll have to write a binary component to invoke `gdk_display_warp_pointer` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No. you cannot move a mouse cursor using javascript.
But you can do this.
Hide the cursor. Load an image shaped like cursor. Animate the image.

Comment: In my xul app I don't know how to hide it, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960411/in-xul-within-a-transparent-window-how-do-i-hide-the-mouse-cursor). If using pure javascript I cannot move it, maybe there's something in Xul that will allow me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nsIDOMWindowUtils.sendNativeMouseEvent(x, y, 0, 0, null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils#sendNativeMouseEvent()) to reposition the mouse cursor. Perhaps combined with [`window.screenX/Y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/screenX) to work out where you should move the cursor to, since `sendNativeMouseEvent` seems to treat the `(x,y)` as  absolute screen coordinates.

I haven't tested this method very thoroughly, so there could be caveats. I can't think of any myself.

I know this is an old question, but I have not seen this solution suggested anywhere before, and it's not exactly obvious.

I've only tested with Firefox v48 on Windows 7. Here, `sendNativeMouseEvent` calls [`SetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx) to perform the actual repositioning.