# In Xul, within a transparent window, how do I hide the mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mouse, xul

I have a Xul window that is transparent, and I need to hide the mouse cursor after 1 second. Applying `cursor: none` will not work, the mouse cursor still shows up in the transparent part of the window.

Any idea how to get rid of the mouse cursor?

Comment: That's because according to the OS your mouse isn't within the window, because it's transparent! Try making the window nearly transparent instead.

Comment: @Neil unfortunately, the system where I work doesn't support semi-transparency. It's just 100% transparent or opaque. (low level graphical issues)

Comment: @Neil your comment should be an answer, if I find no workaround it'll be the correct one. It, for now, just doesn't work for me because of my graphical system issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OS generally won't even bother to send mouse events to a completely transparent (area of your) window; as far as it's concerned, your window isn't there. However if your OS allows it, a nearly transparent window might work.

Comment: I thought transparent would be only visibility, not for events either.. ok so.