# How to have your mouse point at one point when you load a webpage?

Tags: html, css

So I am making a hover game for my webpage. I just want my mouse to automatically point at a point say a button or a box i create with css when that page loads.
is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please post your [**current code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and any **relevant** HTML and/or CSS you are having issues with and a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar), if required, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You can't control the mouse's position, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You can't, not with HTML nor with CSS. Even in Javascript, you can only fake it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409867/move-mouse-cursor-using-javascript-in-chrome-or-firefox-using-any-method-plugin (random pick from several 100s of SO hits).

Answer (score 0):

No.  There's no way for a web page to control the position of the mouse cursor.