# Giving the Cursor a Movement Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

i was wondering, if it is possible, with jquery, to give the cursor a speed so that it moves in one direction if the user isn't using the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the mouse cursor's position from Javascript.

Comment: Is there a possiblity giving the cursor a speed with something else than Javascript..?

Comment: No, these things are handled by the operating system (mouse sensitivity, etc.) and the browser cannot give control over them.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't move the mouse cursor, you can move the elements on your page, so it looks like the mouse cursor is moving...just a trick :)

I learned from this question [Web browser: Hide mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361404/web-browser-hide-mouse-cursor) that you can hide the mouse cursor, so I'm wondering that maybe you can hide it, then emulate a mouse cursor by your self...though it must be a huge project..

Comment: So there is absolutely no possibility of giving the cursor a default speed? But giving the wrapper div a default speed might be an option. How can that be done ? btw thx for the answers already :)

Comment: @Lieven what did you mean by saying **wrapper div** ?

Comment: The thing is I want to distract the users a bit by giving them a sort of resistance while moving the cursor and if it is not beeing moved it should move into the set direction. So using a kind of "fake" cursor wouldn't solve my problem :D

Comment: @Lieven I think that's not possible with JavaScript..imagine when you visit a web page, the cursor automatically move anywhere..

Comment: Yeah I know but that's what I'm willing to achieve, to try and distract the User, to measure his Concentration while using a distracting Interface :)