# Invisible mouse onmouseover in css and html?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mouseover, onmouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to hide the cursor in a webpage using CSS or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript)
>   [Web browser: Hide mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361404/web-browser-hide-mouse-cursor)

I'm making a website and I'm stuck with one problem.
I wonder how I can make the mouse invisible on mouseover in an html element? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With CSS:

```
selector { cursor: none; }
```

Comment: @Viky: I disagree.  He said 'in an HTML element', not the full page...

Comment: @Viky That's not at all what the OP is asking for... he wants the mouse to become invisible after mousing-over an element, NOT the entire page. This is actually the correct approach.

Comment: Really quite unsure as to why Samuel's answer has +2 votes at the time of writing and I have -1.  Especially seeing as in my opinion, mine answers the OP's question better with a specific selector, not to the whole page....  Oh well.

Comment: @2ndDownvoter, please explain why.  I come here to learn, so please teach me a better way of doing this.

Comment: I agree with psynnott. The OP clearly states 'make the mouse invisible on mouseover in an html element'. It doesn't say the entire page/doc, nor does it doesn't mention any specific element. Psynnott answered correctly and gets my upvote.