# Nodewebkit app: hide cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, node-webkit

I'm developing my web app with nodewebkit in fullscreen mode.
It has to be used with touchscreen monitor.

I've used CSS proprerty:

```
html * {
  cursor: none;
}
```

In [nodewebkit's manifest](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format) seems that nothing usefull is provided to remove cursor..

Problem is that cursor disappears only when it is moved the first time.

How can I improve this behavior?

Comment: An option could be to provide a blank cursor. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834929/766921

Comment: Already try, same behavior, same problem!

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the problem calling from script:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
```

But I can't understand why doesn't work from css.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to focus window at first to make the css hiding cursor work?!

I meet the same issue and then have gone with the following code.

```
var gui = require("nw.gui");
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.focus();
```