# Cannot completely remove mouse cursor in nw.js app

Tags: html, css, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm using nw.js for html/css/js desktop app and cannot completely remove mouse cursor in full screen mode.

[image]

I've removed it by setting css properties `cursor: none`, `margin: 0`, `padding: 0` on the body/html. And also `toolbar: false` and `fullscreen: true` are set in package.json.
But the cursor is visible a few pixels on all the edges of screen (picture bellow).

[image]

Strange behaviour, does someone know how to completely remove it?

**NOTE**: This is just an issue in NW.js, as it works perfectly in all browsers and also in the xulrunner, as we migrated in the company from xulrunner to node-webkit (nw.js) all applications got this issue.

Comment: Is your body height and width 100% maybe there are some pixels out of body. Try to set css cursor:none to html tag too

Comment: Like I said in description, `cursor: none` is set for body and html tags.

Comment: does the cursor show up in specific areas or is the reappearance random?

Comment: @Aziz It's not random, picture added to explanation.

Comment: try to add `margin:0; padding:0;` to `html` and `body`.

Comment: Do you have code or a Fiddle ?

Comment: @sebastianbrosch Of course, already done. This is some NW.js specific issue.

Comment: @sscotti Not needed, as this is NW.js specific issue, all is fine in browsers (fullscreen) and xulrunner.

Comment: @swolfish Actually it is needed. We are here guessing what you can do in `html` or `body` or check `margin`, etc., it would be much easier if you showed us your code.

Comment: I don't think margin or padding has any effect on this. see this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/nzpuhr40/

Answer (score 3):

I suspect another element is applying `cursor:auto`, essentially overriding your CSS rule.

Consider the following basic example:

```css
html, body {
  background:#000; color:#FFF;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:none;
}

div {
  margin:2em;
  padding:1em;
  background:#555;
  cursor:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This div has cursor:auto</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the element gets the normal cursor because it has a `cursor:auto` rule.
Since you did not provide your code, I can't know exactly which element is getting the rule, you can inspect in the devtools to catch it. Otherwise, you can **override ALL cursor rules** with this CSS line:

```
* { cursor: none !important; }
```

And to see that in action:

```css
html, body {
  background:#000; color:#FFF;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:none;
}

div {
  margin:2em;
  padding:1em;
  background:#555;
  cursor:auto;
}

* { cursor: none !important; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This div has cursor:auto but gets overriden</p>
</div>
```

---

**Edit: iframes**

The cursor cannot be hidden in documents loaded through an `iframe`. The `iframe` would need to get that CSS rule locally.

See iframe demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/rr7bsrc7/1/

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation, but the problem is in NW.js as it somehow overrides the style or better said ignores.

Comment: It could override with another !important rule which has more specificity. If you have a live demo I can look at it and see what's causing this.

Comment: As I said in description, all our applications have this issue with node-webkit, in the browsers and xulrunner fullscreen everything is ok. But, thanks. ;)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936567/nodewebkit-app-hide-cursor tell me if that JS line fixes your problem `document.body.style.cursor = 'none';`

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have also the same issue. I think the best solution for us would be to switch to Electron or wait until a stable version 0.13 of nw.js is released.